# Select rows with lowest price grouped by another column

Tags: mysql

I have this table.

[image]

I want to select rows with lowest price of each `pg_id`

I have this query

```
SELECT
    *, MIN(product_price)
FROM
    `product_group_scrape_history`
GROUP BY
    pg_id;
```

But its giving me this result

Notice the `date_scraped` column of 1st row. Its `2017-03-01 09:15:17` but it should be `2017-03-09 06:25:41`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to find row with min price in a pg_id, you can find the min price per pg_id in a subquery and then join it with the table to get the desired result.

```
select p1.*
from product_group_scrape_history p1
join (
    select pg_id,
        min(product_price) product_price
    from product_group_scrape_history
    group by pg_id
    ) p2 on p1.pg_id = p2.pg_id
    and p1.product_price = p2.product_price
```

Note that this will return multiple row per pg_id in case there are multiple rows with min product price for that pg_id.

If you really need one row per pg_id with min product price, you can use user variables:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        @rn := if(@pg_id = pg_id, @rn + 1, if(@pg_id := pg_id, 1, 1)) rn
    from (
        select *
        from product_group_scrape_history
        order by pg_id, product_price
    ) t, (select @rn := 0, @pg_id := -1) t2
) t where rn = 1;
```

If you meant to find rows with min price for *each product* in a pg_id, you can use:

```
select p1.*
from product_group_scrape_history p1
join (
    select pg_id,
        product_id,
        min(product_price) product_price
    from product_group_scrape_history
    group by pg_id,
        product_id
    ) p2 on p1.pg_id = p2.pg_id
    and p1.product_price = p2.product_price
    and p1.product_id = p2.product_id;
```

Comment: I want to find just one product per pg

Comment: @Umair - You can use the first one then

Comment: @Umair - Add another alternative if you really want one row per pg. See the second one